# How can I allow one package access to another package's unexported data only when testing?

Tags: testing, go, integration-testing

In *The Go Programming Language*, section 11.2.4, there is an example of of an external test accessing `fmt.isSpace()` via a declaration of `IsSpace` in `fmt`'s `export_test.go` file.  That seemed like the perfect solution, so that's what I did:

`a/a.go`:

```
package a

var x int

func Set(v int) {
    x = v
}
```

`a/a_test.go`:

```
package a
import "testing"

func TestSet(t *testing.T) {
    Set(42)
    if x != 42 {
        t.Errorf("x == %d (expected 42)", x)
    }
}

func Get() int {
    return x
}
```

(Running `go test` in `a/` works fine.)

`b/b.go`:

```
package b
import "path/to/a"

func CallSet() {
    a.Set(105)
}
```

`b/b_test.go`

```
package b
import (
    "testing"
    "path/to/a"
)

func TestCallSet(t *testing.T) {
    CallSet()
    if r := a.Get(); r != 105 {
        t.Errorf("Get() == %d (expected 105)", r)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run `go test` in `b/`, I get:

```
./b_test.go:11: undefined: a.Get
```

Trying to run both sets of test at the same time with `go test ./...` did not help.

After some considerable poking around I discover that "[The *_test.go files are compiled into the package *only when running go test for that package*](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10184)" (emphasis mine).  (So, in other words I could access `a.Get` from an `a_test` external test package in `a/`, but not from any package outside of `a/`.)

Is there some other way I can allow tests from one package to access otherwise-internal data from another package, for integration testing purposes?

Comment: I would appreciate it if the people who are downvoting this question would suggest how it could be improved.

Comment: You can't access unexported identifiers from another package period. This is a basic premise of Go packages, so these testing examples are no different.

Comment: [This talk](https://speakerdeck.com/mitchellh/advanced-testing-with-go?slide=52) on testing Go code, by [hashicorp](https://github.com/hashicorp)'s founder, provides a solution that you may find useful.

Comment: @JimB: "You can't access unexported identifiers from another package period"—that is true but moot.  As the fmt and fmt_test packages show, it is possible to "open a window" to unexported data for external tests—with the somewhat arbitrary (but apparently entirely intentional) limitation that the mechanism only works when the test package is in the same directory as the package with the otherwise-unexported data.

Comment: @mkopriva: There is a lot of good stuff in those slides.  It's a pity there seems to be no way to have `go build` ignore testing.go / testing_*.go.

Comment: Why would you care about package internals in an integration test? This is a perfect example for black-box testing. As the name suggests, the intended purpose is to test the integration of different parts of the system, where you access those specific parts through their public interfaces.

Comment: @cpcallen i'm not 100% sure so don't quote me on this but I think unused symbols are removed by the linker, with a few special cases where they are not, therefore, for example, if your `func` declared in `testing_*.go` is used only in `*_test.go` files, than i suspect it won't make it to the final executable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some other way I can allow tests from one package to access otherwise-internal data from another package, for integration testing purposes?

No. There isn't.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned, there isn't any way to "grant" access to unexported identifiers.

Some clarification on the `fmt` package's tests is needed / justified though.

There are 2 kinds of testing: *black-box* testing and *white-box* testing.

*Black-box* testing is when you treat the package as a "black-box", and you test it only through its exported identifiers (through its "public API", what other packages see). In such cases, the test files have a different package name (e.g. `fmt_test` when testing the `fmt` package).

*White-box* testing is when you make use of both exported and unexported identifiers of the package. To create white-box tests, you specify the same package name in the test files as the package being tested (thus, `fmt` in case of the `fmt` package test).

The tests included in the standard lib's `fmt` package *intend* to be a black-box test, but then it would not be able to test everything. So the Go authors went for a *mixed* version: they included a single `export_test.go` test file which uses the same package declaration (`package fmt`) so it gets access to unexported identifiers of the `fmt` package, and it "exports" 2 identifiers so that the other (black-box) test files will have access to:

```
var IsSpace = isSpace
var Parsenum = parsenum
```

<sup>The authors did so because they wanted to minimize the use of unexported identifiers, and so this explicitly marks what unexported identifiers are used, and basically acts as a "bridge" between the `fmt` package and the black-box tests of the `fmt` package.</sup>

One thing to note here is that these will only be "exported" to the (black-box) tests of the `fmt` package (and white-box tests of `fmt` of course), and not for other packages or tests of other packages. The reason is simply because test files are not parsed and compiled when a package is built, only when package test is run.

**Solution?**

Unexported identifiers are for the package itself and they are no one else's business. Which means no other package should ever want to test them. If they need to be tested, it must be done inside the package's own tests.

If for integration testing you need to access unexported identifiers, then the package must export "something" that either exposes the values (or some parts of them), or aids the testing without exporting the sensitive data or implementation details. If the package API is well designed and its tests are thorough, this should never (rarely) be needed.

Comment: The description of black-box vs. white-box testing may be useful for those not familiar with the concepts.  There are times—when doing integration testing of related packages, notably—when test can be made a lot simpler if they can directly inspect the internal state of another package.

Comment: @cpcallen I still don't think it's worth it. If you change internals of your package (including unexported identifiers) leaving the public API unchanged, that should effect **no one**. If integration tests could access –and therefore rely on– internals of a package (unexported identifiers) could unjustifiably break when package internals change.

Comment: you are absolutely right that white box tests are going to be more brittle, but I kind of think it's my prerogative to decide when it is and isn't worth it.  In some cases it makes the tests much simpler, and a very simple but theoretically-brittle test might be preferable to a very elaborate one that is robust against changes I never make.

Comment: @cpcallen Then simply add an exported function exposing the value, and do comment that it's for testing purposes only and shouldn't be used otherwise.