# Any useful alternative to foo.go + foo_test.go

Tags: go, testing

For unit testing a Go code base, is there any reasonable alternative to the `foo.go` and `foo_test.go` pattern? The only "concern" is having all those extra files in the same place on the filesystem. It might be nice to put the test files in a central place, but that might not work due to the way Go packages work.

Comment: No. This is how Go projects are structured. What about the file count is a concern?

Comment: my boss expressed concern that there might be a better way, so this is my way of telling my boss that there is not lulz :)

Comment: A test file can go anywhere, but if it's not in the same package, then you are limited to black box testing. Best practice is often to do both, depending on what precisely you are testing.

Comment: But even black-box testing files are usually put in the same *directory*, in the `foo_test` package, in order to support black-box testing while keeping the tests organized alongside the code under test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you tell the `go` command to test a package, e.g.

```
go test some/path/mypackage
```

Then the go tool will look for test files in the package's directory. If you put the test files elsewhere, then the go tool will not find them (it will not even look for them) in other folders, so they will not be run / executed.

This argument alone is enough to not put them elsewhere.

Package doc of [`testing`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/):

> To write a new test suite, create a file whose name ends _test.go that contains the TestXxx functions as described here. **Put the file in the same package as the one being tested.**

[Command go: Testing functions:](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Testing_functions)

> The 'go test' command expects to find test, benchmark, and example functions in the "*_test.go" files corresponding to the package under test.

**Some notes:**

- The go tool only expects test files to be in the same folder, but you can name them however you like, you just have to use the `_test.go` suffix. E.g. you may have a `foo.go`, and you may use `my_test.go` for the tests. There is also no requirement to have a separate test file for each `.go` source files, you may put all tests into a single test file, and you may have more test files than source files.
- In the test files, you may use the same package name, and then the test files are compiled together with the package so tests have access to everything–including unexported identifiers–in the package (*white-box* testing). You may use the package name suffixed with `_test`, in which case the tests in those files will only have access to the package's exported identifiers (*black-box* testing). Read more about this here: [How can I allow one package access to another package's unexported data only when testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930944/how-can-i-allow-one-package-access-to-another-packages-unexported-data-only-whe/42931290#42931290)

You shouldn't worry about the number of `.go` files. To go tool will handle even if you have a thousand `.go` files in a package. Although in most cases if you have many `.go` files in a package, that's an indication that the package is doing too much, and it should be broken into multiple, smaller packages.

Comment: thanks. I wanted to do what you mentioned. create one test file per package. and I wanted to name the file  foo/.foo_test.go   or foo/_foo_test.go, but golang won't let me start a file with a dot or underscore. I get this error when I run `go test <filepath>`  => `can't load package: package main: no Go files in (folder)`, so that's kinda lame imo idk, know of a workaround?

Comment: @MrCholo Files and folders starting with an underscore are deliberately ignored by the go tool. The workaround? Just don't start their names with an underscore.

Comment: yes, underscores and dots are both ignored. it would be nice to use a dot in my case, but I will use ∫∫∫∫ instead for now.